# How to optimize this query with some subqueries in it

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, subquery

My query is like this:

```
SELECT date_format( created_at, '%Y-%m-%d' ) AS the_date, 
COUNT(s.id) AS total, 
(SELECT COUNT(ks.id) FROM kc_shares ks WHERE site = 'facebook' AND date_format( created_at, '%Y-%m-%d' ) = the_date ) AS total_facebook, 
(SELECT COUNT(ks.id) FROM kc_shares ks WHERE site = 'twitter' AND date_format( created_at, '%Y-%m-%d' ) = the_date ) AS total_twitter 
FROM `kc_shares` s
GROUP BY `the_date`
```

What I want to get is the number of daily shares with the specification of total, total shares to facebook (thus site = 'facebook') and total shares to twitter. That's why I need the `GROUP BY`.

When it had, like, a few thousands rows, there's no problem. But the table currently has almost 200,000 rows, and the query is very slow, taking about 20-30 seconds, even more I guess.

I've tried adding indices to site and created_at fields but to no avail.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the sub queries are eating up performace. So maybe you can do something like this:

```
SELECT 
    date_format( created_at, '%Y-%m-%d' ) AS the_date, 
    COUNT(s.id) AS total, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.site='facebook' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_facebook, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.site='twitter' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_twitter
FROM 
    `kc_shares` s
GROUP BY 
    `the_date
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Move the subselects so you join against them, rather that doing a subselect for every returned row.

Something like this (untested):-

```
SELECT date_format( created_at, '%Y-%m-%d' ) AS the_date, 
COUNT(s.id) AS total, 
Sub1.total_facebook, Sub2.total_twitter
FROM `kc_shares` s
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT date_format( created_at, '%Y-%m-%d' ) AS sub_date, COUNT(ks.id) AS total_facebook FROM kc_shares ks WHERE site = 'facebook' GROUP BY sub_date ) Sub1 ON date_format( created_at, '%Y-%m-%d' ) = Sub1.sub_date
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT date_format( created_at, '%Y-%m-%d' ) AS sub_date, COUNT(ks.id) AS total_twitter  FROM kc_shares ks WHERE site = 'twitter' GROUP BY sub_date ) Sub2 ON date_format( created_at, '%Y-%m-%d' ) = Sub2.sub_date
GROUP BY `the_date`
```

Although finding a way to do a join on a non derived column (ie the date part of the date / time) would also help. Possibly a good case here for a bit or denormalisation, adding a field for just the date in addtion to the date / time currently stored.

Comment: I've tried moving it to joins, it's much better, the query now takes 6-8 seconds, but @Arion gave the perfect solution. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to change the way the query works. The following would provide rows for each day/site rather than having the two sites on the same row.

```
SELECT 
   date_format( created_at, '%Y-%m-%d' ) AS the_date,site, 
   count(id) 
FROM 
   kc_shares s 
where 
   (site="facebook" or site="twitter") ) 
group by  
   created_at, site
```

I'm assuming that created_at is a date field.

This should provide the same data (I think, I haven't tried it) but in a different format.

Try an index on (created_at,site).

Comment: the reason I did it with subqueries is because there will be another aggregation in the select. So it's like count(id) as total, count(something_id) as total_something, etc. Thus, the result will be nicely formatted so that i can just loop through each day to get the total count of shares whether they are to facebook, twitter, etc plus other aggregated values.